WineHQ packages being held back
I'm new to Linux (not really I've used it for 3 years now) I still don't really know the ins and outs of this OS.
I'm using Ubuntu, and I've stumbled across a problem when I want to update my software. Whenever I do so on the software app I get the error message: Unable to download updates: The following packages have unmet dependencies and it doesn't really show the packages to me. I'm on jammy and I worry that my system might be vulnerable due to it not being up-to-date. That being said, I did sudo apt upgrade, and it just shows me this:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  wine-stable wine-stable-amd64 wine-stable-i386:i386 winehq-stable
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.

Now I think my broken packages are those wine packages, but I don't know what to do now. Should I delete them or try to update them?

Three years is not "new."

It was a joke hahahah

Short answer: Uninstall the held-back Wine packages.
Longer Answer: This is a common Wine question.
The package names suggest you are not using Wine from the Ubuntu repositories, but are instead using Wine from their own non-Ubuntu upstream repos.
This means that it's up to Wine developers to maintain their compatibility with each Ubuntu release. However, they historically have disliked maintaining their older releases. So these kinds of incompatibilities regularly crop up after a few years.
You are welcome to use the older Wine packages from the Ubuntu repositories, which are built to match the older release of Ubuntu that you are running. Had you used the Ubuntu Software application to install Wine, this is what would have been installed. Adding the WineHQ sources is harder, as it requires multiple steps and --as you have discovered-- their support wanes.
If your Wine still works, then you can safely live with those messages for a while. Until the held-back message gets longer or a blocking error occurs. Then you must uninstall the packages.
If you really, really want newer Wine packages, regardless of source, then you must run a newer release of Ubuntu.

Thank you very much <3 Ill stop worrying about it
